# comparing uppercase and lowercase using compareTo() method in java

Tags: java, string, compareto

I want to  compare uppercase and lowercase using `compareTo()` method in java.
Below is the code snippet I have used but not able to understand why it is returning 32.

```
String s1="a"; 
String s2="A";
System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2)); 
//return 32
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation about what the compareTo method does: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html ? Please read it and edit your question to be more specific about what aspect of the method you don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s1.compareTo(s2)
```

Will do:

```
'a' - 'A' => 97 - 65 = 32
```

From Java docs:

> the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument.

Comment: so it's all about ascii. understood.

Answer (score 0):

> Java – String compareTo() Method example. The method compareTo() is used for comparing two strings lexicographically. Each character of both the strings is converted into a Unicode value for comparison. If both the strings are equal then this method returns 0 else it returns positive or negative value.

So `'a' - 'A' => 97 - 65 = 32